# What are the min and max arguments to EdgeDetect?

Tags: image-processing, syntax

What are the min and max arguments to `EdgeDetect`, for all methods and specifically `"Sobel"`?
How do I find the limits or ranges of functions in the future? Or is it 255?

Comment: See [Image Processing](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImageProcessing.html) for the basics on image representation.  Generally, channels and threshholds have a range of 0 to 1.

Comment: You can find default values in the documentation: in the "Details and Options" section. It is most assuredly not 255 as Mathematica scales pixel values between 0 and 1.

Comment: @MichaelE2 @ bill I think this could be a good question, as I think the doc of `EdgeDetect` is not very clear, and there DO be [differences between a threshhold of `1` and `1.1`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gBn4w.png).

Comment: @Silvia Interesting.  I interpreted the question as primarily "How do I find the limits or ranges of functions in the future."  There seems to be a lack of explanation of thresholds and `EdgeDetect` in the docs.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I always do some try-and-fail attempts when using some functions like `EdgeDetect`, I think they really need a more insightful documentation :(

Answer (score 3):

In `EdgeDetect[image, radius, threshold]`, the radius is expressed in pixels, and the threshold corresponds to normalized pixel values (ie. in the range from 0 to 1).

@Silvia, there may be differences between a threshold of 1 and a threshold of 1.1 indeed. Such cases include:

1. "Real" or "Real32" images where pixel values are outside the 0-1 range.
2. Multichannel images for which the vector gradient magnitude is greater than 1.

Comment: So, `Real` images are not normalized in general? Or just in this particular case?

Comment: The normal range for "Real" and "Real32" data type images is from 0 to 1. But these images can also hold values outside the 0-1 range. An example where it expected is `LaplacianFilter` that yields positive and negative pixel values.

Comment: Matthias, I think it would be helpful if you noted in your profile that you work at WRI. Not because it is necessary (it is not), but because it would certainly make this answer credible for users who do not know that you work at WRI :)

Comment: @rm-rf I try to write credible answers that stand by themselves --- falling a bit short at times unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to imply that your answers are not credible/don't stand for themselves... Sometimes, the nature of the _question_ is such that it is impossible for the average user to be able to answer it authoritatively using only the documentation and/or spelunking. In such situations, an answer from someone who actually develops these functions and implements algorithms is much more valuable than speculations. I suppose I actually meant to use the word "authoritative" than "credible" :)

Comment: @rm-rf We had understood each other reasonably well.  I believe it is healthier in the long run if the content of answers is complete without having to speculate on someone's position or other meta-data, apart from reputation that is. For those questions that call for either wild guesses or insider's knowledge, I guess I should write how I know the information. (Looks like a chat better fit for the meta site...)

Comment: Interesting to say the least. So,

Comment: I did img01= image with location  Roughly,  Then came the Suggestion bar that offered EdgeDetection. That with the Manipulate wrapper gave me,  EdgeDetect[%7, 2, 0.07, Method -> "Canny"]    See the 2?  More in depth documentation perhaps?

Comment: @EdgyTector It seems it suggested a default radius of 2. This looks like a very sensible default value to me. You can always change it to the scale that you prefer for your image.

Comment: EdgeDetect question going good. Thank you.    The process has lead me to ask one of the same questions again. How does one get the exact code that Mathematica generates without using Roll Up. That is if I am presented Sliders and other variables to Fix, can I have Mathematica generate the whole that it has offered.   I tried Ctrl Shift E  in the cell. No joy. Is there a buffer that holds the generated, or its in,...   How to get that code.   It could be very helpful presenting data to clients and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the authoritative answer! I can guess case 1 but didn't come up with case 2.